# Fancybox 3 ajax type auto append query string fancybox=true to the actual url

Tags: fancybox-3

Is there a way to avoid Fancybox 3 from automatically appending the query string "fancybox=true"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option `ajax` that you can use to customize your ajax requests, this is the default value:

```
  ajax: {
    // Object containing settings for ajax request
    settings: {
      // This helps to indicate that request comes from the modal
      // Feel free to change naming
      data: {
        fancybox: true
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Janis. This helps. Thought it was more of a customised obj for sending request data, and it turns out to be a jQuery ajax settings obj.